# How to flatten tree via LINQ witch is not bringing the rigth ID?

Tags: c#, linq, tree

So far I've got this code I'm using this to implement on Gantt graphic I'm having some issues because when I'm trying to edit some field on the table it brings me the Id (parent) but not the children's son I must use flat data any idea? thanks in advance :

```
public List<BusinessObject> GetGanttData()

{
    spCliente_Proyectos_GanttTableAdapter DatosTA = new spCliente_Proyectos_GanttTableAdapter();
   DSProyectosPlaneacion.spCliente_Proyectos_GanttDataTable   DatosT = DatosTA.GetDataGantt(idProyecto.Value);

    var hitos = DatosT.Where(x => x.IsidPadreNull()).ToList();
    DateTime dFechaMinima = DatosT.OrderBy(x => x.dFechaI).First().dFechaI;
    DateTime dFechaMaxima = DatosT.OrderByDescending(x => x.dFechaF).First().dFechaF;
    GanttContainer.ScheduleStartDate = dFechaMinima.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    GanttContainer.ScheduleEndDate = dFechaMaxima.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    List<BusinessObject> list = new List<BusinessObject>();

    foreach (var hito in hitos)
    {
        var actividades = DatosT.Where(x => (x.IsidPadreNull() ? 0 : x.idPadre) == hito.idReferencia).ToList();

        List<BusinessObject> listActividades = new List<BusinessObject>();



        foreach (var actividad in actividades)
        {
            var tareas = DatosT.Where(x => (x.IsidPadreNull() ? 0 : x.idPadre) == actividad.id).ToList();
            List<BusinessObject> listTareas = new List<BusinessObject>();

            foreach (var tarea in tareas)
            {
                listTareas.Add(new BusinessObject()
                {
                    Id = (int)tarea.id,  
                    //ParentId =(int)tarea.idReferencia,
                    Name = tarea.sTitulo,                  
                    PercentDone =(int)tarea.fAvance,
                    StartDate = tarea.IsdFechaINull() ? DateTime.Now : tarea.dFechaI,
                    EndDate = tarea.IsdFechaFNull() ? DateTime.Now : tarea.dFechaF,
                    //Children = null
                });
            }

            listActividades.Add(new BusinessObject()
            {
                Id= (int)actividad.id,
               // ParentId = (int) actividad.idReferencia,
                Name = actividad.sTitulo,
                PercentDone =(int)actividad.fAvance,
                StartDate = actividad.IsdFechaINull() ? DateTime.Now : actividad.dFechaI,
                EndDate = actividad.IsdFechaFNull() ? DateTime.Now : actividad.dFechaF,
                //Children = listTareas
            });


        }

        list.Add(new BusinessObject()
        {
            Id = (int)hito.idReferencia,
            Name = hito.sTitulo,
            PercentDone =(int)hito.fAvance,
            StartDate = hito.IsdFechaINull() ? DateTime.Now : hito.dFechaI,
            EndDate = hito.IsdFechaFNull() ? DateTime.Now : hito.dFechaF,
           // Children = listActividades
        });
    }

    return list;

}
```

What I need to get is Self-referential(flat data) data binding .. Any idea of how can I achieve this?

Comment: Where exactly do you want this behavior to occur ?

Comment: Usually you can flatten data with SelectMany, which roughly converts an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> to an IEnumerable<T>.